# Flutter: closing bottom sheets

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm using Get package for state management and I also use `Get.bottomSheet()` command.
I want to close the sheet and I know I can use `Navigator.pop()` but in this example:

```
Get.bottomSheet()
await Future.delay(Duration(seconds: 3))
Navigator.pop()
```

if user close bottom sheet in that 3 seconds, `Navigator.pop()` will close other things.
So is there a command to close just `bottomSheets`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **Navigator.pop()**.

Use instear **Get.back();**

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific method for bottomsheets. As seen on [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/get#:%7E:text=To%20close%20snackbars%2C%20dialogs%2C%20bottomsheets), `Get.back()` is used to close snackbars, dialogs, bottomsheets, etc.

To make sure that it will run on the bottomsheet, you can add the condition:

```
if(Get.isBottomSheetOpen ?? false){
   Get.back();
}
```